Airflow 2.9. bug ImportError: cannot import name '_run_inline_trigger' from 'airflow.models.dag'
I am facing some kind of bug in apache-airflow 2.9.2
This error ocurrs on random DAGs, on random tasks and very frequently, but not always (quite strange as the it is getting more frequently as the days goes):
ImportError: cannot import name '_run_inline_trigger' from 'airflow.models.dag' (/data/user/airflow_env/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py)
I am using CeleryExecutor, this error is on worker. When I run it with LocalExecutor, it runs fine. The thing is I need to run it on CeleryExecutor/
Any idea what could be causing it?
I have reviewed the package /data/user/airflow_env/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py and there is actualy a definition of the function with such name, so I tried to rename it to _run_inline_trigger2 and changed all the calls as well, in case it was also imported from airflow.models.dag package with the same name, but the error still occurs.
